# How to merge two arrays of dates ignoring duplicate dates and then sort by date

Tags: php, arrays, date

For example, I have $dates1 and $dates2 shown below, and want to create $dates3, which keeps all dates in $dates1, and adds any unique dates in $dates2, ignoring any duplicates. The arrays contain other values but I'm just showing the dates because that's what I want to merge/sort on.

$dates1=

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [day] => 2012-01-01
        [foo] => "bar"
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [day] => 2012-01-02
        [foo] => "bar"
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [day] => 2012-01-03
        [foo] => "bar"
    )
)
```

$dates2=

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [day] => 2011-12-31
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [day] => 2012-01-01
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [day] => 2012-01-02
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [day] => 2012-01-03
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [day] => 2012-01-04
    )
)
```

So I would like to merge $dates2 into $dates1, ignoring any duplicates, to make $dates3:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [day] => 2011-12-31
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [day] => 2012-01-01
        [foo] => "bar"
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [day] => 2012-01-02
        [foo] => "bar"
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [day] => 2012-01-03
        [foo] => "bar"
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [day] => 2012-01-04
    )
)
```

Comment: Hint... `array_multisort()` and `array_unique()` are your friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, do you mean something like this?

```
    $old_array = array_merge($dates1, $dates2);
    $new_array = array();
    foreach ($old_array as $item){
        if (!array_key_exists($item['day'], $new_array)){
            $new_array[$item['day']] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $new_array;
```

Comment: hmm just tried this after trying Pratt's answer and I'm having the same issue (last element seems to be missing after the foreach).. must be the issue is on my end.. let me try a few more things..

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
$a1 = array(array('day' => '2012-01-01', 'foo' => 'bar1'),
            array('day' => '2012-01-02', 'foo' => 'bar2'),
            array('day' => '2012-01-03', 'foo' => 'bar3'));

$a2 = array(array('day' => '2011-12-31'),
            array('day' => '2012-01-01'),
            array('day' => '2012-01-02'),
            array('day' => '2012-01-03'),
            array('day' => '2012-01-04'));

$orderedArray = array();
foreach (array_merge($a1, $a2) as $v)
{
    if (count($v) == 1 && isset($orderedArray[$v['day']]))
        continue;

    $orderedArray[$v['day']] = $v;
}
ksort($orderedArray);

print_r($orderedArray);
```

Edit: I refactored the code.

Comment: This is almost working for me except it seems to be dropping the last element in array_merge($a1, $a2)..

Comment: I mean that after finishing the foreach, if i print_r($orderedArray), the last element (in your example -> array('day' => '2012-01-04')), is missing, but i noticed that this happened with the other answer (zerg ling) as well, so might be the issue is on my end.. will try a few more things..